# What's the process of building an Universal/Isomorphic React/Redux web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

Hey I'm a javascript beginner and have been trying to figure out how to build an Isomorphic Web Application with React/Redux. I've seen a bunch of examples and tutorials, but couldn't figure out how to begin such an application and how to structure the project. So far I'm unable to understand how actions, components, reducers, routes, etc interact with one another. 
I know I lack some basic understanding of concepts, but I want to begin by learning React and not other frameworks, if possible. Can anyone help me out explaining how to plan and structure such project?

Comment: Or you can try a starter kit, there are really good ones. If I can offer my version of davezuko's starter kit: https://github.com/janoist1/universal-react-redux-starter-kit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much JavaScript knowledge you know, if you haven't got any prior JavaScript knowledge, I think React/Redux is bit advanced thing for you to learn at the moment. I think the better approach for you is trying to understand the JavaScript, the language itself first. Try some online tutorials or read some books about fundamentals.

After you have some basic understanding of JavaScript, you can study React/Redux. Read the Redux [Documentation](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/introduction/index.html) and examples.

I've been programming in JavaScript many years, but I have to read Redux docs a few times before understand it.

You can also try to build a counter example using Redux from scratch. [Counter example.](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/counter)  Don't aim too big if you don't have the same level of the language.

Good luck. Keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is to take a look at real life isomorphic application - https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall

And here is my post which covers a lot of isomorphic issues step by step ["The Pain and the Joy of creating isomorphic apps in ReactJS"](http://blog.koorchik.com/isomorphic-react/)